# Bluetooth not working (Intel wireless ac 9560)

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

My bluetooth signals are weak so I tried using a bluetooth dongle but it didn't work. Now the default Intel bluetooth card is not working as well, wifi works fine.

I see the bluetooth option in the top panel but it doesn't do anything, here is the settings menu:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbJ0u.png)

Output for lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Output for sudo service bluetooth status:

```
● bluetooth.service - LSB: Start bluetooth daemons
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bluetooth; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-09-12 20:37:24 IST; 14min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 858 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bluetooth start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 12 20:37:24 HP-Pavilion systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start bluetooth daemons...
Sep 12 20:37:24 HP-Pavilion systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start bluetooth daemons.
```